# How can I extract a value from inside an xml tag using Nokogiri?

Tags: xml, nokogiri

How can I extract the `ID` from `TrackInfo` below?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <TrackResponse> <TrackInfo ID="9400110200883105817710"> <TrackSummary>Your item departed our ATLANTA, GA 30320 sort facility on February 25, 2014. Information, if available, is updated periodically throughout the day. Please check again later.</TrackSummary> <TrackDetail>Processed through USPS Sort Facility, February 25, 2014, 11:54 am, ATLANTA, GA 30320</TrackDetail> <TrackDetail>Depart USPS Sort Facility, February 22, 2014, ORLANDO, FL 32824</TrackDetail> <TrackDetail>Processed at USPS Origin Sort Facility, February 21, 2014, 4:39 am, ORLANDO, FL 32824</TrackDetail> <TrackDetail>Accepted at USPS Origin Sort Facility, February 21, 2014, 3:24 am, ORLANDO, FL 32819</TrackDetail> <TrackDetail>Electronic Shipping Info Received, February 15, 2014</TrackDetail> </TrackInfo> </TrackResponse>
```

When I try `@xml.xpath('//TrackInfo')` I'm getting the entire body rather then just the ID.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@` to select an attribute node:

```
@xml.xpath('//TrackInfo/@ID')
```

(You could also specify the `attribute` axis directly – `//TrackInfo/attribute::ID` – but the abbreviated `@` syntax is normally used.)